# When I update url with Vue router and than refresh the page, the content won't remain the same

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue-cli

I have the problem with refreshing the page !

My code works like this:
When I click the button from the dropdown menu, it updates the url without refreshing the page, and some content is being changed.

- I am using (vue router).

But when I refresh the page on that updated url, the content changes back, before the button was clicked. -  Which I don't want !

I can't find the answer on google ...

- I would appreciate your help

Here are the screenshots of my project...

[content before button is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnhCJ.png)

[content when button was clicked and updated url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HA7nk.png)

[content which i don't like to be,  when page is refreshed on updated url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsyiD.png)

[THE CONTENT I WANT WHEN YOU REFRESH THE UPDATED URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqsQl.png)

content of component DropDown.vue file:

```
<ul
  v-if="open"
  class="pf-c-select__menu"
  aria-labelledby="select-single-typeahead-expanded-label"
  role="listbox"
>
  <li v-for="option in filteredOptions" :key="option" role="presentation">
    <button
      style="padding: 0px 0px"
      :class="{ 'pf-m-selected': option === modelValue }"
      class="pf-c-select__menu-item optionBtn"
      role="option"
      @click.stop="
        $emit('update:modelValue', option);
        open = false;
      "
    >
      <router-link :to="{ path: `/api/storages/${option}` }">
        {{ option }}
        <span
          v-if="option === modelValue"
          class="pf-c-select__menu-item-icon"
        >
          <i class="fas fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </router-link>
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

content of main.ts file:

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    { path: "/api/storages/:storage", component: AppContent },
    { path: "/", component: AppContent },
  ],
});
```